# Indoor Atlas: Get checkpoint list created

Tags: ios, ios7, indoor-positioning-system

I just analysed on IndoorAtlas and tried the sample application using ios SDK. I got my location to be updating in the floor plan I have created when I move around.

I was wondering how should I get message when I reached a point where I have created a checkpoint within the floor. How should i notify user when I reach a place that I have created in floor plan.

I have checked if any function available in IndoorAtlas ios SDK so that I can get list of checkpoints available in that Floor.

Please let me know if there is any function or property available to get those done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

the waypoints you use for mapping are at the moment just for the mapping purpose with MapCreator2, there's no API for fetching those and using for e.g. the use you describe. For that use case you could do for example geofencing.

BR,

Elina, IndoorAtlas

Comment: Then, how should I alert a user regarding the place detail to the user when they reached that point?? Where should i save those points in floor plan??

Comment: That would be up to the geofencing API you choose to use in your implementation.

Comment: Hi.. Can you please tell me any geofencing API names that you used? Or any name that i should try?